# Unexpected behavior with as_completed in concurrent.futures using python.

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency

I am struggling with using concurrent.futures in python. I am trying to iterate over a large number of S3 objects. Due to the number of accounts, buckets, and objects this can take a very long time. Longer than my STS credentials are good for and long enough I don't trust the script wont otherwise be interrupted.

I would expect the following code to work and while it does produce the output that I am looking for when tested with a small number of buckets it only writes to the completed and out files after completely processing every bucket rather than after each future returns. If it gets interrupted the completed and out files are not written to.  Even if many buckets have already been processed successfully.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args_results = parser.parse_args()

    completed = open(args_results.completed, 'a+')
    out = open(args_results.out, 'a+')  

    done = getCompleted(args_results.completed) 
    todo = getBuckets(args_results.todo)

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        futures = []
        for item in todo: 
            if item not in done:
                account, bucket = item.split('|')
                futures.append(executor.submit(getBucketInfo, account, bucket))

        for x in as_completed(futures):
            result = x.result()
            out.write(result + '\n')
            completed.write(result['Account'] + '|' + result['Bucket'] + '\n')
```

Am I misunderstanding how the as_completed() functionality is suppose to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add line buffering when opening the files so they would flush to disk with every line written.

```
completed = open(args_results.completed, 'a+', buffering=1)
out = open(args_results.out, 'a+', buffering=1)
```

Problem solved.